# THREE.js - Is it possible to repeat different texture maps at different intervals

Tags: three.js

I want to create some scrolling textures that have a displacement map scrolling in a different direction at a different rate. Unfortunately, I can't seem to set the size of the tiles for the texture and displacement map separately from each other. Is there a way to do this in THREE.js?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.repeat

Comment: You should try asking this type of open-ended question at https://discourse.threejs.org/

Comment: @probitaille when you set the texture to repeat for one map all the other texture mappings of a material get set to that as well. What I want is to have different repeat values set for different maps on a material

Comment: @marquizzo I'll go ahead and post there, thanks!